# "cypher.client" transaction issue in c# cant error and commited

Tags: neo4j, transactions, neo4jclient

I'm using Cypher.Client Transaction in my queries.
my transaction is committed without problem. however in every create and update that runs OK, one of my relations doesn't update. i wonder if the problem is in my transaction or there is a bug in my code. how can i detect what went wrong?

Some of these transaction work properly , though . But there 's a problem .

sample open transaction:

> ```
>         var txClient = (ITransactionalGraphClient)aClient;
>         using (var tx = txClient.BeginTransaction())
>         { my query!}
> ```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Match` scope for extra relation which will cause the transaction no to be
commit.